# Is there any Python XML parser that was designed with humans in mind?

Tags: python, xml, user-friendly

I like Python, but I don't want to write 10 lines just to get an attribute from an element. Maybe it's just me, but `minidom` isn't that `mini`. The code I have to write in order to parse something using it looks a lot like Java code.

Is there something that is more `user-friendly` ? Something with overloaded operators, and which maps elements to objects?

I'd like to be able to access this :

```
<root>
<node value="30">text</node>
</root>
```

as something like this :

```
obj = parse(xml_string)
print obj.node.value
```

and not using `getChildren` or some other methods like that.

Comment: Does XPath count as user friendly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python

Comment: I'd be very much interested in a Java version of this!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should take a look at [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm). It's not doing exactly what you want but it's a lot better then minidom. If I remember correctly, starting from python 2.4, it's included in the standard libraries. For more speed use cElementTree. For more more speed (and more features) you can use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) (check the objectify API for your needs/approach).

I should add that [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) do partly what you want. There's also [Amara](http://uche.ogbuji.net/tech/4suite/amara/) that have this approach.

Comment: Agreed, ElementTree is super-easy to use. Not so great with fancy-namespaces (yet) but getting better all the time. Avoid minidom when possible.

Comment: I've had a terrible time trying to read namespaced documents with elementtree, currently stuck reading with minidom and writing with elementtree :-/

Answer (score 3):

I actually wrote a library that does things exactly the way you imagined it.  The library is called "xe" and you can get it from: http://home.avvanta.com/~steveha/xe.html

xe can import XML to let you work with the data in an object-oriented way.  It actually uses xml.dom.minidom to do the parsing, but then it walks over the resulting tree and packs the data into xe objects.

EDIT: Okay, I went ahead and implemented your example in xe, so you can see how it works.  Here are classes to implement the XML you showed:

```
import xe

class Node(xe.TextElement):
    def __init__(self, text="", value=None):
        xe.TextElement.__init__(self, "node", text)
        if value is not None:
            self.attrs["value"] = value

class Root(xe.NestElement):
    def __init__(self):
        xe.NestElement.__init__(self, "root")
        self.node = Node()
```

And here is an example of using the above.  I put your sample XML into a file called "example.xml", but you could also just put it into a string and pass the string.

```
>>> root = Root()
>>> print root
<root/>
>>> root.import_xml("example.xml")
<Root object at 0xb7e0c52c>
>>> print root
<root>
    <node value="30">text</node>
</root>
>>> print root.node.attrs["value"]
30
>>>
```

Note that in this example, the type of "value" will be a string.  If you really need attributes of another type, that's possible too with a little bit of work, but I didn't bother for this example.  (If you look at PyFeed, there is a class for OPML that has an attribute that isn't text.)

Answer (score 2):

I had same need for simple xml parser and after a long time spent on checking different libraries I found [xmltramp](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/xmltramp/).

Based on your example xml:

```
import xmltramp

xml_string = """<root>
<node value="30">text</node>
</root>"""

obj = xmltramp.parse(xml_string)
print obj.node('value')             # 30
print str(obj.node)                 # text
```

I didn't found anything more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a fair bit of time going through the examples provided above and through the repositories listed on pip.

The easiest (and most Pythonic) way of parsing XML that I have found so far has been XMLToDict - https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

The example from the documentation available at GitHub above is copy-pasted below; It's made life VERY simple and EASY for me a LOT of times;

```
>>> doc = xmltodict.parse("""
... <mydocument has="an attribute">
...   <and>
...     <many>elements</many>
...     <many>more elements</many>
...   </and>
...   <plus a="complex">
...     element as well
...   </plus>
... </mydocument>
... """)
>>>
>>> doc['mydocument']['@has']
u'an attribute'
>>> doc['mydocument']['and']['many']
[u'elements', u'more elements']
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['@a']
u'complex'
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['#text']
u'element as well'
```

It works really well and gave me just what I was looking for. However, if you're looking at reverse transformations, that is an entirely different matter altogether.