# Easiest way to read this XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to loop through this XML to get specifically to the `count` fields.

What's the most efficient way to do this? I don't mind using libraries as long as they don't require root access to install since I'm on shared hosting. Is using libraries supposed to be a better practice or the opposite?

```
<category>
  <name>Category 1</name>
  <subcategories>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 1.1</name>
          <count>18</count>
      <subcategory>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 1.2</name>
          <count>29</count>
      <subcategory>
  <subcategories>
<category>

<category>
  <name>Category 2</name>
  <subcategories>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 2.1</name>
          <count>18</count>
      <subcategory>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 2.2</name>
          <count>29</count>
      <subcategory>
  <subcategories>
<category>
```

Comment: What language? What platform? This is not valid XML, by the way. There is no root element.

Comment: Am too lazy to find an appropriate duplicate. Have a look at [some of my previous answers about PHP's DOM extension and XML](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+xml+dom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a simple [XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) query, you can get all `count` tags with one sentence. Provided the library you are using to access/parse the XML provides you with an XPATH API.

A simple python example (inspired in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python) SO question) could by:

```
import libxml2

doc = libxml2.parseFile("tst.xml")
ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
res = ctxt.xpathEval("count")
// do something with res here (should contain count nodes)
doc.freeDoc()
ctxt.xpathFreeContext()
```

Since you've just added PHP to the question, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) is a LINK on how to do XPATH on PHP.

Comment: You beat me to this : )

But stacker really needs to add a root element to his/her XML sample, and then use something like //subcategory/count

Answer (score 2):

I use Linq to XML. However the fact that you've not stated your development platform makes it impossible to answer.

Comment: True. If you're on .NET 3, LinqToXML will be even better (IMHO) than XPATH.