# Extract URLs from specific tags in python

Tags: python, url, tags, extract

all.
I have an huge html file which contains tags like these:

```
<h3 class="r">
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm" class=l onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','','6','','0CDEQFjACOAM')">
```

I need to extract all the urls from this page in python.

In a loop:

1. Find occurences of    `<h3 class="r">`    one by one.
2. Extract the url

http://xrayoptics.by.ru/database/misc/goog2text.py I need to re-write this script to extract all the links found on google.

How can i achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: If you now say this is to parse google search results, I'd use Google's [custom search api](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html). Yes, you can only do about a 100 for free a day, but google will also require you to enter captchas if they detect you are querying them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html>
...
<h3 class="r">
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm" class=l
   onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','','6','','0CDEQFjACOAM')">
text</a>
</h3>
...
<h3>Don't find me!</h3>
<h3 class="r"><a>Don't find me!</a></h3>
<h3 class="r"><a class="l">Don't error on missing href!</a></h3>
...
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for h3 in soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "r"}):
  for a in h3.findAll("a", {"class": "l", "href": True}):
    print a["href"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use XPATH, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python) for a question what package would be appropriate in Python.

Comment: Just curious as to why XPATH over BeautifulSoup? I've never used XPATH, but BeautifulSoup seems to be a standard answer for HTML/XML parsing as per the OP's question.

Comment: I tend to work with more rigid formats, and prefer plainer errors. BeautifulSoup could indeed be a better answer if the HTML isn't to be trusted though, but I'd still be tempted to us XPath because of it's portability.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *Regular Expressions* (RegEx) for that.
This RegEx will catch all URL's beginning with *http* and surrounded by quotes (*"*):

```
http([^\"]+)
```

And this is how it's done in Python:

```
import re
myRegEx = re.compile("http([^\"]+)")
myResults = MyRegEx.search('<source>')
```

Replace  by the variable storing the source code you want to search for URL's.

*myResults.start()* and *myResults.end()* now contain the starting and ending position of the URL's. Use the *myResults.group()* function to find the string that matched the RegEx.

If anything isn't clear yet, just ask.

Comment: Well, that page belongs to a google query. What I need to achieve is that I want to extract all the websites' links from a google search.Well, take a look at that code: http://xrayoptics.by.ru/database/misc/goog2text.py
Maybe you can rewrite this? That'd be easier for you :)

Comment: @RobinJ this does not actually solve the OP's problem. The OP requested links within `<H3>` tags.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested yet? I know a bit of Python, but I'm not that good myself. The most complicated thing I've achieved so far is to make an IRC bot in it, wich crashes after about 5 minutes. Regular Expressions seems to be the easiest solution to me.
@KyloWpppd: My bad, I forgot. I'm taking a look if I can't find something for that.

Comment: Regexes are about the most brittle solutions for this. At best, they usually work on a limited subset of html, at worst, your regexes become pages long and extremely unwieldy. Do a quick SO search on HTML/XML & regexes, and you'll see it's generally frowned upon save for very specific cases.

Comment: The best solution I found is just finding whatever is between the <h3 class="r"> tags, and then applying the RegEx I suggested above on it.

Comment: is it possible for you to make the required adjustments on the script I posted above in order for it to function properly? because I am not familiar with python :(