# regex not returning match but there is clearly a match

Tags: python, html, regex

I am searching an html formatted site for a string ("s") which has this format:

```
<td class="number">$0.48</td>
```

I am trying to return the "$0.48" by using a regex.  It was working until today and I have no idea what changed, but here is my snippet of code:

```
def scrubdividata(ticker):
    sleep(1.0) # Time in seconds.
    f = urllib2.urlopen('the url')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "Annual Dividend:" in line:
            print 'for ticker %s, annual dividend is in line'%(ticker)
            s = str(lines[i+1])
            print s
            start = '>$'
            end = '</td>'
            AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
```

Here is the result:

```
for ticker A, annual dividend is in line

    <td class="number">$0.48</td>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 115, in <module>
    scrubdividata(ticker)
  File "test.py", line 34, in scrubdividata
    LastDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I am using python 2.5 (I believe).  I have heard never to use regex with html, but I needed to quickly use my limited knowledge to get the job done asap and regex is the only way I know of.  Now, am I suffering the consequences or is there another issue that's causing this?  Any insights would be wonderful!

Thanks, B

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python

Comment: Thank you Everyone for your help.  Problem Solved!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> "$"      Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at
>          the end of the string.

So you probably want to escape the dollar sign on this line like so:

```
start = '>\$'
```

If you're considering doing more searching through HTML in the future, I would suggest you take a look at the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module. It's a bit more forgiving than regex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollar sign.

```
start = '>\$'
end = '</td>'
AnnualDiv = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
```

The reason is that the `$` is a special character in regex. (It matches the end of a string or before the newline.)

This will set `AnnualDiv` to the string `'0.48'`.  If you want to add the `$`, you can do it using this:

```
AnnualDiv = "$%s" % re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
```