# Removing tags when using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, kodi

trying to scrape a website for a personal script in Kodi, My code is working but when BS is presenting the content it still has the tags on it. Reletavily new to Python so looking for easy to understand answers please.

Current output:

```
<li>
  <span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-size:16px;color:#EFEFEF;">
      04:30 - 05:30 The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon
      <span style="color:#999999;">
        - Channel 34
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Wanted output:

```
04:30 - 05:30 The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon - Channel 34
```

My Code:

```
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon
import urllib, urllib2, re, HTMLParser, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pg_source = ''
req = urllib2.Request('http://rushmore.tv/schedule')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36')

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    pg_source = response.read().decode('utf-8' , 'ignore')
    response.close()
except:
    pass

content = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_source)
content = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('ul', { 'id' : 'myUL' }).prettify())

xbmcgui.Dialog().textviewer(str(content), str(content))
xbmcgui.Window
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `xpath` ?

Comment: I have not tried xpath no. Could you ellaborate please?

Comment: It's just about extracting the text content which `prettify` does not do.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python/13504511` here is an example how to use it. You could either use it with `lxml` or pure python by `import xpath`

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Sorry still learning, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I am using `find_next` method to get the second span

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = """<li>
<span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;">
<span style="font-size:16px;color:#EFEFEF;">
04:30 - 05:30 The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon
<span style="color:#999999;">
- Channel 34
</span>
</span>
</span>
</li>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(d, "html.parser")
print soup.find("li").span.find_next('span').get_text()
#or
print soup.find("li").find("span", {"style": "font-size:16px;color:#EFEFEF;"}).text
```

**Output:**

```
04:30 - 05:30 The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon - Channel 34
```

Comment: That looks like something I could use. How could I implement that into my code? I have tried get_text but it returned this error and I am not sure how to rectify it.

Error Contents: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4210: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The error looks like you have non-English chars in your text

Comment: Is there a way to bypass that? the text I'm scraping is on a website and changes daily so there's not really a way I can change it before scraping. If that makes sense. Thank you btw

Comment: try response.read().encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach. It should get you the desired results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://rushmore.tv/schedule")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for content in soup.select("#myUL span[style*='#EFEFEF']"):
    print(content.text)
```

Partial output:

```
16:00 - 20:00 Tennis: ATP Dubai  - 13 (720P / US) & 21 (720P / CA)
16:00 - 20:00 Tennis: ATP Dubai  - 13 (720P / US)
17:00 - 21:00 Golic and Wingo - Channel 03
18:45 - 23:00 Snooker: Welsh Open - Channel 105
20:00 - 23:30 The Dan Patrick Show - Channel 11
```

Comment: That's great, thank you, but when using this I am getting indentation error. Python runs this as normal but Kodi not. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that. Was my fault. Just have "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml." possibly a Kodi error. I'll try to fix this, Thank you.

Comment: Try changing this line from `BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")` to `BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")`. Hope it will fix the issue. Btw, as it solves the issue make sure to accept it as an answer by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: that seemed to fix that,but now I'm getting ascii error again, would this indicate there is a problem with the website i'm scraping? - Error Contents: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: ok, while this works, it's scraping every individual element each time rather than altogether. If you understand?