# How to extract text from an element that does not have an xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the dollar sign rating for each restaurant on a food delivery website, however, there is no available xpath.

```
<!-- react-text: 2108 -->
"$$"
<!-- /react-text -->
```

The above code is what is used for the dollar ratings from when I inspected the website. I've tried using the line directly above:

```
    <i class="icon-bullet--small">·</i>
```

However, this outputs the period since it is not for the dollar rating.
I've also tried using:

```
    cost = ['//li[{}]/a/div[2]/p[2]/!'.format(x) for x in range(1, 999)]
```

as well as using "!--" and "react" and "react-text" in the xpath, but none of it works. 
Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: @zx485 I'm not sure what you mean. I haven't received any answers.

Comment: No pressure, though. If the answers *really* didn't solve your problem, then you don't need to accept them. If they *did* solve your problem, I would highly recommend accepting them.

Comment: Update the question with some more of the outerHTML containing the element `"$$"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//comment()[normalize-space() = "react-text: 2108"]/following-sibling::text()
```

will select the text node immediately following the targeted comment, returning

```
"$$"
```

as requested.

---

**Important note:** [@DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) has helpfully pointed out that the comment containing `react-text: 2108` is a React directive that Selenium won't see unless the content is extracted as `page_source`.   Thanks, Debanjan!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm very new to Python, so I unsuccessfully attempted

    cost = ['//comment()[. = "react-text: {}"]'/following-sibling::text()]
  for costrating in cost[:999]:
   dollarrating = driver.find_element_by_xpath(costrating).text
   print(dollarrating)

Comment: See [How to use Xpath in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python).  No use repeating that all here.  The interesting part of your question is how to write an XPath relative to comments.

Comment: If the comment content you want get has a parent node, you can also get it by `//parent-node/text()`

Comment: @kjhughes `react-text: 2108` indicates it's a react element (generated dynamically). Selenium won't be able to recognize/interact with this content unless extracted as `page_source`