# Looking for a way to Replace multiple entries in an XML file

Tags: python, xml, replace, notepad++

Noob here looking for some help.
I have an XML exported from a certain software, which contains the name of the entries using a format.
I also have an excel spreadsheet with the equivalent names that I would need to replace.

For example, the XML file contains this format:

XML Code:

[image]

And I have a table with an entry for each name (UWI above)

Excel table:

[image]

I have tried in excel, but then I cannot export. Also I tried in Notepad++ with Python, but I am too much of a noob to make it work.

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: To go through the XML you could use something like XPATH
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.