# Recursively add a block of rows in different xsl files

Tags: python, bash, xslt

I have a main xsl file and I would like to include in it two xsl files.
I tried using the include function of XSL but without success. I read some examples on the web but I always got the following error:
*element include only allowed as child of stylesheet*
Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
In the following the main.xsl file I'm using where I inserted the xsl:include already:
main.xsl:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:include href="distributor.xsl"/>
<mdb:MD_Metadata xmlns:mri="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mri/1.0"
xmlns:mas="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mas/1.0"
xmlns:mrs="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrs/1.0"
xmlns:mda="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mda/1.0"
xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"
xmlns:mdt="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdt/2.0"
xmlns:msr="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/msr/2.0"
xmlns:gex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gex/1.0"
xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
xmlns:gcx="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gcx/1.0"
xmlns:mco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mco/1.0"
xmlns:mds="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mds/2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:gfc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19110/gfc/1.1"
xmlns:srv="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/srv/2.1"
xmlns:mac="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mac/2.0"
xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
xmlns:mdq="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19157/-2/mdq/1.0"
xmlns:mex="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mex/1.0"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:mrl="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrl/2.0"
xmlns:mmi="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mmi/1.0"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
xmlns:mrc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrc/2.0"
xmlns:cat="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cat/1.0"
xmlns:mrd="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mrd/1.0"
xmlns:mpc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mpc/1.0"
 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
 xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
 xmlns:old="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
 xmlns:old_gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<!-- DEFINE global variable here -->

<xsl:variable name="geonetwork_server" select="'http://myserver'" />
<xsl:variable name="webgis_geoserver" select="'http://webgis/geoserver/'" />
<xsl:variable name="openeo_collections" select="'https://mycollections/'" />
<xsl:variable name="collection_thumb_folder" select="'https://thumb_collections/'" />
<!-- **************************  -->
   <mdb:metadataIdentifier>
      <mcc:MD_Identifier>
         <mcc:code>
        <gco:CharacterString>$UUID</gco:CharacterString>
         </mcc:code>
         <mcc:codeSpace>
            <gco:CharacterString>urn:uuid</gco:CharacterString>
         </mcc:codeSpace>
      </mcc:MD_Identifier>
  </mdb:metadataIdentifier>
   <mdb:defaultLocale>
      <lan:PT_Locale id="EN">
         <lan:language>
            <lan:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="eng"/>
         </lan:language>
         <lan:characterEncoding>
            <lan:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode"
                                     codeListValue="utf8"/>
         </lan:characterEncoding>
      </lan:PT_Locale>
   </mdb:defaultLocale>
   <mdb:metadataScope>
      <mdb:MD_MetadataScope>
         <mdb:resourceScope>
            <mcc:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode"
                              codeListValue="dataset"/>
         </mdb:resourceScope>
      </mdb:MD_MetadataScope>
  </mdb:metadataScope>
   <mdb:contact>
      <cit:CI_Responsibility>
         <cit:role>
            <cit:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode"
                             codeListValue="pointOfContact"/>
         </cit:role>
         <cit:party>
            <cit:CI_Organisation>
               <cit:name>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Institute </gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:name>
               <cit:contactInfo>
                  <cit:CI_Contact>
                     <cit:address>
                        <cit:CI_Address>
                           <cit:deliveryPoint>
                              <gco:CharacterString>address</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:deliveryPoint>
                           <cit:city>
                              <gco:CharacterString>city</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:city>
                           <cit:administrativeArea>
                              <gco:CharacterString>area</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:administrativeArea>
                           <cit:postalCode>
                              <gco:CharacterString>CAP</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:postalCode>
                           <cit:country>
                              <gco:CharacterString>nation</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:country>
                           <cit:electronicMailAddress>
                              <gco:CharacterString>email@gmail.com</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:electronicMailAddress>
                        </cit:CI_Address>
                     </cit:address>
                     <cit:onlineResource>
                        <cit:CI_OnlineResource>
                           <cit:linkage>
                              <gco:CharacterString>http://my_website</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:linkage>
                           <cit:protocol>
                              <gco:CharacterString>WWW:LINK-1.0-http--link</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:protocol>
                           <cit:applicationProfile>
                              <gco:CharacterString>profile</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:applicationProfile>
                           <cit:name>
                              <gco:CharacterString>name</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:name>
                           <cit:function>
                              <cit:CI_OnLineFunctionCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_OnLineFunctionCode"
                                                         codeListValue="information"/>
                           </cit:function>
                        </cit:CI_OnlineResource>
                     </cit:onlineResource>
                  </cit:CI_Contact>
               </cit:contactInfo>
               <cit:individual>
                  <cit:CI_Individual>
                     <cit:name>
                        <gco:CharacterString>Bruce Banner</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:name>
                     <cit:positionName>
                        <gco:CharacterString>Researcher</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:positionName>
                  </cit:CI_Individual>
               </cit:individual>
            </cit:CI_Organisation>
         </cit:party>
      </cit:CI_Responsibility>
  </mdb:contact>
   <mdb:dateInfo>
      <cit:CI_Date>
         <cit:date>
            <gco:DateTime>$DATE_REVISION</gco:DateTime>
         </cit:date>
         <cit:dateType>
            <cit:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"
                                 codeListValue="revision"/>
         </cit:dateType>
      </cit:CI_Date>
  </mdb:dateInfo>
   <mdb:dateInfo>
      <cit:CI_Date>
         <cit:date>
            <gco:DateTime><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/creation_time" /></gco:DateTime>
         </cit:date>
         <cit:dateType>
            <cit:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"
                                 codeListValue="creation">creation</cit:CI_DateTypeCode>
         </cit:dateType>
      </cit:CI_Date>

  </mdb:dateInfo>
   <mdb:metadataStandard>
      <cit:CI_Citation>
         <cit:title>
            <gco:CharacterString>ISO 19115-3</gco:CharacterString>
         </cit:title>
      </cit:CI_Citation>
  </mdb:metadataStandard>
   <mdb:metadataLinkage>
      <cit:CI_OnlineResource>
         <cit:linkage>
            <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="$geonetwork_server" />$UUID</gco:CharacterString>
         </cit:linkage>
         <cit:function>
            <cit:CI_OnLineFunctionCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_OnLineFunctionCode"
                                       codeListValue="completeMetadata"/>
         </cit:function>
      </cit:CI_OnlineResource>
  </mdb:metadataLinkage>
   <mdb:spatialRepresentationInfo>
      <msr:MD_GridSpatialRepresentation>
         <msr:numberOfDimensions>
            <gco:Integer>2</gco:Integer>
         </msr:numberOfDimensions>
         <msr:axisDimensionProperties>
            <msr:MD_Dimension>
               <msr:dimensionName>
                  <msr:MD_DimensionNameTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_DimensionNameTypeCode"
                                                codeListValue="row"/>
               </msr:dimensionName>
               <msr:dimensionSize>
                  <gco:Integer><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/properties/dimensions/rows" /></gco:Integer>
               </msr:dimensionSize>
               <msr:resolution>
                  <gco:Distance uom="m"><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/properties/bands/band[@bandId=1]/gsd" /></gco:Distance>
               </msr:resolution>
                <msr:dimensionTitle gco:nilReason="missing">
                  <gco:CharacterString/>
               </msr:dimensionTitle>
               <msr:dimensionDescription>
                  <gco:CharacterString>dims description </gco:CharacterString>
               </msr:dimensionDescription>
            </msr:MD_Dimension>
         </msr:axisDimensionProperties>


         <msr:axisDimensionProperties>
            <msr:MD_Dimension>
               <msr:dimensionName>
                  <msr:MD_DimensionNameTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_DimensionNameTypeCode"
                                                codeListValue="column"/>
               </msr:dimensionName>
               <msr:dimensionSize>
                  <gco:Integer><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/properties/dimensions/columns" /></gco:Integer>
               </msr:dimensionSize>
               <msr:resolution>
                  <gco:Length uom="m"><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/properties/bands/band[@bandId=1]/gsd" /></gco:Length>
               </msr:resolution>
               <msr:dimensionTitle gco:nilReason="missing">
                  <gco:CharacterString/>
               </msr:dimensionTitle>
               <msr:dimensionDescription>
                  <gco:CharacterString>dims description </gco:CharacterString>
               </msr:dimensionDescription>
            </msr:MD_Dimension>
         </msr:axisDimensionProperties>
         <msr:cellGeometry>
            <msr:MD_CellGeometryCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_CellGeometryCode"
                                     codeListValue="area"/>
         </msr:cellGeometry>
         <msr:transformationParameterAvailability>
            <gco:Boolean>false</gco:Boolean>
         </msr:transformationParameterAvailability>
      </msr:MD_GridSpatialRepresentation>
   </mdb:spatialRepresentationInfo>

   <mdb:referenceSystemInfo>
      <mrs:MD_ReferenceSystem>
         <mrs:referenceSystemIdentifier>
                <mcc:MD_Identifier>
               <mcc:code>
                  <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/extent/spatial/epsg" /></gco:CharacterString>
               </mcc:code>
               <mcc:codeSpace>
                  <gco:CharacterString>EPSG</gco:CharacterString>
               </mcc:codeSpace>
               <mcc:description>
                  <gco:CharacterString>WGS-84</gco:CharacterString>
               </mcc:description>
            </mcc:MD_Identifier>
         </mrs:referenceSystemIdentifier>
         <mrs:referenceSystemType>
            <mrs:MD_ReferenceSystemTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ReferenceSystemTypeCode"
                                            codeListValue="projected"/>
         </mrs:referenceSystemType>
      </mrs:MD_ReferenceSystem>
  </mdb:referenceSystemInfo>
   <mdb:identificationInfo>
      <mri:MD_DataIdentification>
         <mri:citation>
            <cit:CI_Citation>
               <cit:title>
                   <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/title" /></gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:title>
               <cit:alternateTitle>
                   <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/id" /></gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:alternateTitle>
               <cit:date>
                  <cit:CI_Date>
                     <cit:date>
                        <gco:DateTime>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/creation_time" />
                        </gco:DateTime>
                     </cit:date>
                     <cit:dateType>
                        <cit:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"
                                             codeListValue="creation"/>
                     </cit:dateType>
                  </cit:CI_Date>
               </cit:date>
                           <!-- TEST INCLUDE -->
                           <!-- <xsl:include href = "publication_date.xsl"/>-->
                           <!-- TEST INCLUDE -->

               <cit:edition>
                  <gco:CharacterString>INSERT HERE THE CURRENT VERSION OF THE CITED RESOURCE</gco:CharacterString>
               </cit:edition>
               <cit:identifier>
                  <mcc:MD_Identifier>
                     <mcc:code>
                        <gco:CharacterString>publisher</gco:CharacterString>
                     </mcc:code>
                     <mcc:codeSpace>
                        <xsl:variable name="my_collection_id" select="/STAC/metadata/id"/>
                        <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="concat($openeo_collections,$my_collection_id)"/></gco:CharacterString>
                     </mcc:codeSpace>
                  </mcc:MD_Identifier>
               </cit:identifier>
               <cit:presentationForm>
                  <cit:CI_PresentationFormCode codeListValue="mapDigital"
                                               codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_PresentationFormCode"/>
               </cit:presentationForm>
            </cit:CI_Citation>
         </mri:citation>
         <mri:abstract>
            <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/description" /></gco:CharacterString>
         </mri:abstract>
         <mri:purpose>
                <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/citation" /></gco:CharacterString>
         </mri:purpose>
         <mri:status>
            <mcc:MD_ProgressCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ProgressCode"
                                 codeListValue="onGoing"/>
         </mri:status>
         <mri:pointOfContact>
            <cit:CI_Responsibility>
               <cit:role>
                  <cit:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode"
                                   codeListValue="custodian"/>
               </cit:role>
               <cit:party>
                  <cit:CI_Organisation>
                     <cit:name>
                        <gco:CharacterString>Organisation</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:name>
                     <cit:contactInfo>
                        <cit:CI_Contact>
                           <cit:address>
                              <cit:CI_Address>
                                 <cit:deliveryPoint>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>address</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:deliveryPoint>
                                 <cit:city>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>city</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:city>
                                 <cit:administrativeArea>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>Area</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:administrativeArea>
                                 <cit:postalCode>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>Postal_code</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:postalCode>
                                 <cit:country>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>nation</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:country>
                                 <cit:electronicMailAddress>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>email</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:electronicMailAddress>
                              </cit:CI_Address>
                           </cit:address>
                           <cit:onlineResource>
                              <cit:CI_OnlineResource>
                                 <cit:linkage>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>http://www.my_web.it</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:linkage>
                                 <cit:protocol>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>WWW:LINK-1.0-http--link</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:protocol>
                                 <cit:name>
                                    <gco:CharacterString>eurac research</gco:CharacterString>
                                 </cit:name>
                                 <cit:function>
                                    <cit:CI_OnLineFunctionCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_OnLineFunctionCode"
                                                               codeListValue="information"/>
                                 </cit:function>
                              </cit:CI_OnlineResource>
                           </cit:onlineResource>
                        </cit:CI_Contact>
                     </cit:contactInfo>
                     <cit:logo>
                        <mcc:MD_BrowseGraphic>
                           <mcc:fileName>
                              <gco:CharacterString>logo.jpg</gco:CharacterString>
                           </mcc:fileName>
                           <mcc:fileDescription>
                              <gco:CharacterString>Project logo</gco:CharacterString>
                           </mcc:fileDescription>
                           <mcc:fileType>
                              <gco:CharacterString>JPEG</gco:CharacterString>
                           </mcc:fileType>
                        </mcc:MD_BrowseGraphic>
                     </cit:logo>

        <xsl:for-each select="/STAC/metadata/properties/responsibles/responsible">

           <cit:individual>
                        <cit:CI_Individual>
                           <cit:name>

                                      <gco:CharacterString> <xsl:value-of select="."/></gco:CharacterString>

                              </cit:name>
                           <cit:positionName>
                                <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:positionName>
                        </cit:CI_Individual>
                     </cit:individual>
                 </xsl:for-each>

                  </cit:CI_Organisation>
               </cit:party>
            </cit:CI_Responsibility>
        </mri:pointOfContact>
         <mri:spatialRepresentationType>
            <mcc:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode"
                                                  codeListValue="grid"/>
         </mri:spatialRepresentationType>
        <!-- <mri:topicCategory>
            <mri:MD_TopicCategoryCode>Land</mri:MD_TopicCategoryCode>
         </mri:topicCategory>-->
 </mri:MD_DataIdentification>
 </mdb:identificationInfo>
   <mdb:distributionInfo>
      <mrd:MD_Distribution>
         <mrd:distributionFormat>
            <mrd:MD_Format>
               <mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
                  <cit:CI_Citation>
                     <cit:title>
                        <gco:CharacterString>WCS</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:title>
                     <cit:date gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
                     <cit:edition>
                        <gco:CharacterString>2.0</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:edition>
                  </cit:CI_Citation>
               </mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
            </mrd:MD_Format>
         </mrd:distributionFormat>
                 <!-- TEST INCLUDE -->
           <!-- <xsl:include href = "distributor.xsl"/> -->
                <xsl:call-template name="distributor.xsl"/>
                 <!-- TEST INCLUDE -->
         <mrd:transferOptions>
            <mrd:MD_DigitalTransferOptions>
               <mrd:onLine>
                  <cit:CI_OnlineResource>
                     <cit:linkage>
                        <gco:CharacterString>https://my_collections/</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:linkage>
                     <cit:protocol>
                        <gco:CharacterString>OGC:WCS</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:protocol>
                     <cit:name>
                        <gco:CharacterString><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/id" /></gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:name>
                     <cit:description>
                        <gco:CharacterString>DESCRIBE HERE THE RESOURCE</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:description>
                     <cit:function>
                        <cit:CI_OnLineFunctionCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#CI_OnLineFunctionCode"
                                                   codeListValue="fileAccess"/>
                     </cit:function>
                  </cit:CI_OnlineResource>
               </mrd:onLine>
            </mrd:MD_DigitalTransferOptions>
         </mrd:transferOptions>
      </mrd:MD_Distribution>
  </mdb:distributionInfo>

</mdb:MD_Metadata>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

these are the two xsl to be included: publication_date.xsl

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
<!-- HERE the same namespace as in main.xsl -->
<cit:date>
  <cit:CI_Date>
     <cit:date>
      <gco:Date><xsl:value-of select="/STAC/metadata/creation_time" /></gco:Date>
     </cit:date>
     <cit:dateType>
      <cit:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="publication"/>
     </cit:dateType>
  </cit:CI_Date>
</cit:date>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

distributor.xsl

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--        <xsl:template match="/">-->
        <xsl:template name="DOI_publisher.xsl">
<!-- HERE the same namespace as in main.xsl -->
<mrd:distributor>
            <mrd:MD_Distributor>
               <mrd:distributorContact>
                  <cit:CI_Responsibility>
                     <cit:role>
                        <cit:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#CI_RoleCode"
                                         codeListValue="publisher"/>
                     </cit:role>
                     <cit:party>
                        <cit:CI_Organisation>
                           <cit:name>
                              <gco:CharacterString>institute2</gco:CharacterString>
                           </cit:name>
                           <cit:contactInfo>
                              <cit:CI_Contact>
                                 <cit:address>
                                    <cit:CI_Address>
                                       <cit:deliveryPoint>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>address2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:deliveryPoint>
                                       <cit:city>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>city2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:city>
                                       <cit:administrativeArea>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>area2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:administrativeArea>
                                       <cit:postalCode>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>Postal_code2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:postalCode>
                                       <cit:country>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>Nation2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:country>
                                       <cit:electronicMailAddress>
                                          <gco:CharacterString>email2</gco:CharacterString>
                                       </cit:electronicMailAddress>
                                    </cit:CI_Address>
                                 </cit:address>
                              </cit:CI_Contact>
                           </cit:contactInfo>
                        </cit:CI_Organisation>
                     </cit:party>
                  </cit:CI_Responsibility>
               </mrd:distributorContact>
            </mrd:MD_Distributor>
    </mrd:distributor>

</mdb:MD_Metadata>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but closely related: [xpath for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python), in particular the answer by Gringo Suave.

Comment: XSLT can be processed by XSLT to achieve that, you can run XSLT from Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it using XSLT?

Note, if you've got a series of similar XSLT files and you need to make a similar change to each of them, this is a strong signal that it's time to do some refactoring to improve code re-use. The simplest approach is to extract common code into shared modules that you incorporate using `xsl:include`. There are other more elaborate approaches, such as generating the XSLT stylesheets from a common master. The fact that XSLT is XML makes manipulating XSLT using XSLT a very viable technique.

**LATER**

OK, you've taken my suggestion, and you've modified your question to show where you got to and where you got stuck. That's not actually a very good way of taking things forward on SO: if you keep editing the question and I keep editing the answer, then anyone coming here later will find it very hard to follow. Next time, raise a new question.

You've misunderstood how `xsl:include` works. At the point where you've written `xsl:include`, replace it with `<xsl:call-template name="some.code"/>`. Put the `xsl:include` declaration at the top level of the `main.xsl` stylesheet (as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`), and in the included module, include a named template `<xsl:template name="some.code">....</xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As you can see I added here the files I'm trying to use but without success. Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong with my files?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad behavior but I thought it could offer a better comprehension of my question. I will keep this in mind for the future.

y the way, I'm still not able to really understand the use of ```xsl:include```. 
I follow your suggestion but when I run the  ```xsltproc ```  I get this error:

```xsltproc -o include_test.xml main.xsl ADO_EU_DEM_25m_3035.xml```

*runtime error: file main.xsl line 442 element call-template
The called template 'distributor.xsl' was not found.
error: file ADO_EU_DEM_25m_3035.xml
xsltRunStylesheet : run failed*

Comment: I think I found the problem. I forgot to insert *.xsl* in the  distributor.xsl file 
now it is 

```<xsl:template name="distributor.xsl">```

and the corresponding section has been added :)